# How to build a ListView based on JSON object and pass its data around after onItemClick

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

Not sure if the title accurately describes what I'm trying to do, but here goes...

My app receives the following JSON object from the server:

```
[{"id":"0","code":"1234","name":"thing"}]
```

I want to create a ListView all of those items (the amount of items in the JSON always varies) and only display the value of the `"name"` field in my ListView. So my list should look like this for the user:

```
thing
another thing
third thing
...
```

Now I want to retrieve the value of `"code"` from the JSON object for that particular `"name"` when it is clicked on the ListView. So with the object above it would give me `"1234"` when `"thing"` was clicked.

Later I wish to send the `"code"` to another activity and do some followup queries to the database using it, but for now I can't seem to get any of this to work.

I am aware that with what I have right now, the `"code"` is not visible to the program because I build my ListView from Strings of `"name"` from the JSON object

I have the following OnClickListener

```
search_results.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  // ListView item is clicked!
  }
});
```

My ListView is built like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    stocks[i] = obj.getString( "name" );
}

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
search_results.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Note: I have tried to use MatrixCursor, but after hours of fiddling around with it, I just gave up... Basically I built a MatrixCursor the same way I built my stocks[] and was hoping to return the index of the clicked ListView item and then just use that index on the MatrixCursor because I assume they would be pointing to the same thing? I'm not sure this is the right way to do this though. And in the end I couldn't figure it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object, POJO, reflecting your JSON object. Something like this :

```
class MyObject {
  String id;
  String code;
  String name;
}
```

Then, use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to creates your list of objects from your JSON.

After that, you will be able to create an Adapter to deal with `MyObject` class instead of String. It would be easier to retrieve the information of the item you've clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you ask I think it would be a good idea for you to consider using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

**1. Create a simple POJO class**

And parse your JSON into, then store the POJO in an `ArrayList`.

```
class MyPojo{
  private String id;
  private String code;
  private String name;

  //Dont forget to add your getters and setters...
}
```

**2. Switch your ListView for RecyclerView**

I suggest you take a look at this tutorial for using `Recycler View`.
[Recycler View Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

From there on everything else would be pretty intuitive.

If you need any more help comment.